# @page.title: SystemStackError (stack level too deep)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have problem with creating new Page.

Page model:

**1.9.2-p180** :002 > Page

```
 => Page(id: integer, meta_keywords: text, meta_description: text, title: string, header: string, url: string, teaser: text, content: text, publicated_at: date, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, parent_id: integer, lft: integer, rgt: integer)
```

And get this massage:
**> Page.new**

```
SystemStackError: stack level too deep
    from /home/raz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@travel/gems/globalize3- .3.0/lib/globalize.rb:60
```

in rails console.

In **PRY** i got this:

```
[3] pry(main)> @page=Page.new
=> #<Page:0x5c86630>
[4] pry(main)> @page.id
=> nil
[5] pry(main)> @page.title
SystemStackError: stack level too deep
from /home/raz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@travel/gems/pry-0.9.11.3/lib/pry/pry_instance.rb:327
[6] pry(main)> @page.content
SystemStackError: stack level too deep
from /home/raz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@travel/gems/pry-0.9.11.3/lib/pry/pry_instance.rb:327
```

Page.rb:

```
class Page < ActiveRecord::Base
  translates :meta_keywords, :meta_description, :title, :header, :teaser, :content
  acts_as_nested_set

  has_one :gallery
  has_one :hotel_numbers_data
  has_one :tour_prices_data
  ... differnt def...
end
```

new method in **pages_controller**:

```
def new
@page = Page.new
if params[:parent_id]      
  @page.parent_id = params[:parent_id]
  binding.pry     
end
respond_to do |format|
  binding.pry
  format.html { render :layout => "admin" }
  format.xml  { render :xml => @page }
end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just need to implement translation table or comment follow line:
translates :meta_keywords, :meta_description, :title, :header, :teaser, :content
in page model